# How do I work effectively with SOS debugging extensions?

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, sos

When I use .load SOS in Visual Studio's immediate window and accitentally issued a command that result in a long list of output (e.g. !dumpheap -type System.String -min 100), the immediate window just can't stop listing the values and keeps scrolling for hours. All I can do is kill the process and restart debugging. This is very annoying. Do you know of any way how I can cancel this listing in the immediate window or have any other tip how I can better use the SOS debugging extensions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have much experience using SOS from within Visual Studio.  But when used from within WinDbg (SOS's original home) you can break most commands by hitting CTRL+Break.  I'm not sure if Visual Studio will have the same processing but it's worth a shot.

Comment: Visual Studio doesn't have CTRL+Break. I use WinDBG now.